# run local application from jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In the same way that some web applications can redirect to local applications, is there a way (magic, extension) to open a local application from a jupyter notebook.
I mean the notebook would open the application, not on the server running the notebook but on the laptop running the notebook.

Comment: What kind of app do you want to run?

Comment: i think about an exe or a dll installed on the local pc